# Choosing an area on a Mac OS X Desktop

Tags: macos, screen-grab

If you press cmd+shift+4 in Mac OS X you are able to select an area on your screen with the corrosponding coordinates shown. I need to implement such a function in one of my applications and have no idea of how to do it. Could anyone give me some advices on that?

Thx.

Comment: Are you looking for a native Carbon/Cocoa API?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to implement that feature ... possibly setting up a window which is transparent and inserting a view that could respond to user interactions ... would this be the way to go? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is done with an translucent overlay window which covers the entire desktop space.

Apple's got some [older sample code](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/) which should give you a start.

Answer (score 2):

This code fragment will return a CGImageRef that contains everything shown on the desktop for a given rectangle. It requires the ApplicationServices framework. The screen coordinates are flipped and the origin is at the top-left corner of the screen. In this case, the image ref would be owned by the caller and would need to be released with `CGImageRelease` when the caller was finished with it.

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

CGImageRef createScreenCapture(CGRect rect) {
  CGImageRef image = CGWindowCreateImage(
                       rect,
                       kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
                       0,
                       kCGWindowImageDefault);
  return image;
}
```

Comment: 10.5-only, it's worth noting.

Comment: @Chuck: Thanks, definitely worth mentioning!